# why script can not be suspended/paused?

Tags: autohotkey, systray

I wrote this simple AHK script, it's working. But rightclick systray icon- suspend/pause, it just still keep working. Is it because of something in my code? or about win7 x64?

```
#Persistent
return

OnClipboardChange:
WinGetActiveTitle, OutputVar 
IfWinExist, collect.doc 
{
    WinActivate       ; use the window found above
    send,^v
    send,{Enter}
    winactivate,%Outputvar%
}
else
    tooltip,need collect doc,400,400
Sleep 100
return
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both [Pause](http://www.autohotkey.com/docs/commands/Pause.htm) and [Suspend](http://www.autohotkey.com/docs/commands/Suspend.htm) are not meant to block automatically called subroutines like `OnClipboardChange` or `GuiClose`. `Pause` merely blocks the **current thread**, which means that every newly created thread will still run, and a clipboard change does create a new thread. Ergo, `Pause` can't block it.
In such cases, you need to implement an own piece of logic within the "event subroutine" that checks some kind of *state*.
Going with your premise to make the functionality depend on the *paused* state, a fairly easy way would be to check for the built-in `A_IsPaused`:

```
OnClipboardChange:
    if(A_IsPaused) {
        return
    }
    msgbox, 'sup?
return
```

There are certainly many ways to implement this. You could also define your own hotkey to activate/deactivate/toggle a custom state.

**P.S:**
Activating a window only to paste some text seems a bit unnecessary and bothersome to me; have a look at the `Control` commands (e.g. [Control, EditPaste](http://www.autohotkey.com/docs/commands/Control.htm)) or access Word via **COM**. Depending on what you do, I believe directly writing to a text file and/or in-memory storage might be a better alternative to a running Word instance anyway.

**P.P.S:**
You might want to be careful with such a negligent clipboard logger. I assume you don't want every kind of data (e.g. passwords) showing up there.